# Magento redirect 301 home

Tags: magento, redirect

I having a problem with google. It has indexed my website with non-friendly url like this 
`mydomain.com/home?param=22` but I have friendly url.

I'd like to redirect (301) `mydomain.com/home?param=22` to `mydomain.com/` using htaccess

ps: I'm using Magento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Magento's .htaccess add this line just below `RewriteBase` line:

```
RewriteRule ^home/?$ /? [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: What I need is redirect all possibles with /home to / and not only param=22

Comment: In my .htaccess file RewriteBase is comment like this #RewriteBase. May I need to discomment?

Comment: Check the edited answer and copy it below RewriteBase line. Yes usually having RewriteBase line is better but if it has been working for you then leave it commented.

Comment: Nothing happened. I need something like this: if the URL has "/home" or every /home? with parameters, then redirect to home page "/".  For example: "/home", "/home?", "/home?param=22", "/home?param=22&cat=3" always redirect (301) to "/"

Comment: Ok edited it again. Just copy paste this line just below RewriteBase line.